# Could not parse payload: payload[0] = < (Android RequestFactory isn't authenticated)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, rpc, payload

I'm developing an application with GAE and Android using RPC. But when I try to send a 
RPCall from Android to the server I get the following error.

```
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[domiii.1992@gmail.com]
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718): java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not parse payload: payload[0] = <
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.vm.impl.JsonSplittable.create(JsonSplittable.java:70)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.StringQuoter.split(StringQuoter.java:73)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.AutoBeanCodex.decode(AutoBeanCodex.java:54)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$StandardPayloadDialect.processPayload(AbstractRequestContext.java:323)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext$5.onTransportSuccess(AbstractRequestContext.java:1108)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.cloudsmsplus.util.AndroidRequestTransport.send(AndroidRequestTransport.java:68)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.doFire(AbstractRequestContext.java:1102)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequestContext.fire(AbstractRequestContext.java:569)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.fire(AbstractRequest.java:54)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.impl.AbstractRequest.fire(AbstractRequest.java:59)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.cloudsmsplus.c2dm.DeviceRegistrar.registerOrUnregister(DeviceRegistrar.java:70)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.cloudsmsplus.C2DMReceiver.onRegistered(C2DMReceiver.java:51)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.handleRegistration(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:191)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver.onHandleIntent(C2DMBaseReceiver.java:110)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 12:00:57.445: E/AndroidRuntime(30718):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

To access my app the user has to be authenticated, so I set the security constraint to * for every url. Even though I'm generating the cookie I get this error. I think the the response I get is the login page.

In my case I send a RPCall to register the device for C2DM. And the most of the code I use was generated with the Appengine connected Android project.
Did someone already found an workaround or fix for that.

PS:
I'm using GAE 1.6.3,
Android API v8,
GWT 2.4.0 (but I think this doesn't matter)

**Edit:**

Ok I found something new. If you send something from Android to App Engine using RPC the client isn't actually authenticated. You just get the token, followed by the cookie and then (so I think) the RequestFactory includes the cookie just as an extra data field. So my web.xml on App Engine looked like this:

```
<!-- Require user login for every access -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

To access my application the user has to be authenticated, no matter which URL he is requesting. Since the RequestFactory isn't authenticated the server response with the html of the login page and the Android client throws the error "Could not parse payload." The weird thing is, that you can send authenticated RPCs from the GWT side and I don't understand why the developers of this API did it that way, that the GWT side is able to send those authenticated calls and the Android side isn't able to send them.

What I did now is that I excluded the gwtRequest servlet from my security constraint with this additional lines in the web.xml

```
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
```

I also noticed, if you create a new App Engine connected Android project that the web.xml just sets the required authentication on the ProjectName.html.

Comment: Good find @Dominic.  I had the same problem and this fixed it.  I had the same url-pattern for my initial security constraint (<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>)  I used this because otherwise it did not seem to ask for authentication.  Did you set your url-pattern that way for the same reason?

Comment: I set the url-pattern to /* because the user has to be authenticated to use my app at all. If you set it to /secret/* for example it will only ask for authentication if you access a /secret url not if you request /foo or /index.jsp 
@aez